# How to explicitly push a function inside callback queue?

Tags: javascript, callback, event-loop

I want to run a function namely '**callbackfn**' after the **setTimeout** function is being executed .If i run it in my global execution context then only when the code inside **callbackfn** is being executed then **setTimeout** Function will run as it will go inside callback queue and will be on hold until the lines in the global execution context.

But what i want is to execute **callbackfn**  after the setTimeout is being executed.For that i have to push the **callbackfn** inside callback queue.So,how can we explicitly push it inside callback queue.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't push your function directly to the queue without something like setTimeout.
to understand why you should know

1. setTimeout is a web API feature that takes the ref of you're
   function and after the timer is done it pushes the function to the
   callback queue
2. the event loop won't dequeue any function from the callback queue
   to the call stack until all the synchronous code is executed then it
   checks the microtask queue first
3. finally if you don't have any waiting functions in the call stack and in the microtask queue (queued functions from promises and mutation observers) it starts to check the callback queue

- you can check this [blog](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) for more information
- if you're a video person check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)